# how can i reduce the height of the rows in tableOutput Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, xtable

i want to reduce the height in the rows of a table building with tableOutput
i tried with the next code, but not works

in `UI.R`:

```
 tableOutput("table"),tag$tr(tags$style(type="text/css", "#table {line-height:50%}"))
```

but not works, also i tried in `server.R`

```
 output$table<- renderTable({
 print(data())
 },include.rownames=F,html.table.attributes=list(cellspacing="10px"))
```

but not works

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- Although you named your data table `table` in `ui.R`, it is actually the id of its container (a `<div>` element), not the `<table>` itself.
- Shiny set the `line-height` attribute at `<td>` level, so in order to override that, you have to set `line-height` at `<td>` level as well.

Below is a working one:

```
tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "#table table td {line-height:50%;}"))
```

You can use this to replace your `tags$tr(...)` part.

Comment: sorry! i've other question if i want to change styles in the header, should i use `#table table header`?

Comment: Maybe `#table table th`?